# Forward errors from exec() to a file

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I am using `exec()`. How can I send anything that is echoed out into one file and all errors into another file?

Here is what I currently have:

```
exec("$php_locataion $cwd/phpExcel.php \"$data\" > $cwd/phpExcel.txt &");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
exec("$php_locataion $cwd/phpExcel.php \"$data\" > $cwd/phpExcel.txt 2>error.txt &");
```

Here `2>error.txt` will redirect stderr to the file error.txt.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be what I want!